# How should be htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, getparameter

example adress: mysite.com/search/?q=notebook

my rewrite rule;

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ example.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
```

this rule ignore `?q`= characters.
How should be htaccess rewrite rule for accept this special character?

Comment: Maybe you need to use [the B flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)? (Only guessing, because problem description isn’t that clear.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just `QSA` flag here:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ example.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.